# ggplot2 not plotting second factor on bar graph

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

This is my code used to create a table:

```
    cmv2<-ddply(cmv, c("treatment", "year"), summarise,
    mean.num.rattles=mean(plant.tot.rat, na.rm=TRUE),
    sd=sd(plant.tot.rat, na.rm=TRUE),
    n=sum(!is.na(plant.tot.rat)),
    se=sd/sqrt(n))
```

This produced a table like I wanted:

```
    treatment year mean.num.rattles        sd  n        se
1     control 2014         978.5833  727.5570 12 210.02763
2     control 2015        1373.8500 1124.5589 12 324.63219
3  early-high 2014         906.8364  600.2020 11 180.96772
4  early-high 2015         615.7455  373.9880 11 112.76161
5   early-low 2014         655.8500  472.1869 12 136.30863
6   early-low 2015         770.5000  647.2640 10 204.68284
7   late-high 2014         218.4923  260.0087 13  72.11344
8   late-high 2015         865.5833 1317.3728 12 380.29278
9    late-low 2014         461.6667  509.2678 12 147.01296
10   late-low 2015         513.1800  475.1837 10 150.26630
```

However, when I try to apply by ggplot code:

```
    p<-ggplot(cmv2, aes(x=treatment,y=mean.num.rattles, fill=year))+ 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="white", colour="black", position="dodge")
```

I get an image that looks like this:

[image]

Do you know where I went wrong in my code?

Comment: What is your expected output? You specified `fill` twice, so its overriding the `fill` in `aes`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sumedh. I'm trying to get the graph to show each treatment in two different years. I took out the  extra "fill", but I got the same thing. p<-ggplot(cmv2, aes(x=treatment,y=mean.num.rattles, fill=year))+ 
geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge")

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: `ggplot(df, aes(x=treatment,y=mean.num.rattles, fill=factor(year)))+ 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")`

Comment: We need 'cmv' to reproduce it, can you edit and provide info on cmv as well?

Comment: I think that you want  `geom_bar(stat="identity",position= position_dodge())`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Pj_, next time I will make my code reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sumedh! This code ended up working by removing the irrelevant fill="white" and colour="black" in the code. Also adding factor(year) into the code was very important.

```
    ggplot(cmv2, aes(x=treatment,y=mean.num.rattles, fill=factor(year)))+ geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

Comment: The fill from attribute overrides fill defined within aesthetics.

Comment: Yes also that! Thank you Pj_!